# materialize modal function does not initialize

Tags: html, materialize

I am using the materialize modal function from http://materializecss.com/modals.html

I cannot get the modal to pop up

I am using the following code:
http://pastebin.com/3L7G8vgK

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your html is malformed with an erroneous `</table>` tag, and you're not using the materialize classes properly. You've only defined one modal to show so only those two modals pointing at the `#footer` modal will even be shown. (The first and last `On` buttons are working, for example. See the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ngbhr07m/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsbin demo](https://jsbin.com/yuhuyicafe/edit?html,js,console,output). First you should add the class and id on anchor element for this to work like: `<a class="modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>` . And your script which initializes modal should be located under the jquery and materialze js.